# Error: import { } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework

when I try to import '@angular/fire/firestore' into my project, I immediately get this error in the console: Error: node_modules/rxfire/firestore/lite/interfaces.d.ts:8:29 - error TS2314: Generic type 'AggregateQuerySnapshot< T>' requires 1 type argument(s).

```
    import { Injectable, inject } from '@angular/core';
    import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
    import { getAuth, signInWithEmailAndPassword, 
             createUserWithEmailAndPassword, updateProfile } from 
             'firebase/auth';
    import { User } from '../models/user.model';
    import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
    import { getFirestore, setDoc, doc } from 
             '@angular/fire/firestore';


    export class FirebaseService {
    auth = inject(AngularFireAuth);
    firestore = inject(AngularFirestore);

    setDocument(path: string, data: any) {
    return setDoc(doc(getFirestore(), path), data);

  }


}
```

```
Error: node_modules/rxfire/firestore/lite/interfaces.d.ts:8:29 - error TS2314: Generic type 'AggregateQuerySnapshot<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).
[ng]
[ng]  8 export type CountSnapshot = lite.AggregateQuerySnapshot<{
[ng]                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng]  9     count: lite.AggregateField<number>;
[ng]    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] 10 }, any, DocumentData>;
```

I am using firebase 9.23.0
@angular/fire 7.6.1

Comment: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/rxfire/issues/88#issuecomment-1715851191

Comment: ready, I solved it by installing rxfire@6.0.3. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Ready, I solved it by installing rxfire@6.0.3